# R Shiny: Use update* From Outside a Module

Tags: r, shiny

What's the best way to use update* from outside a Shiny module without repeating the callModule() call or arguments?

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

numericInputModUI <- function (id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    numericInput(ns("val"), "Value", value = 0),
    textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
}

numericInputMod <- function (input, output, session,
                             updateVal = NA, displayText = "default text") {
  output$text <- renderText(displayText)
  if (!is.na(updateVal)) updateNumericInput(session, "val", value = updateVal)
}

ui = fluidPage(
  numericInputModUI("module"),
  actionButton("updateBad", label = "Bad Update"),
  actionButton("updateBetter", label = "Better Update")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(numericInputMod, "module", displayText = "original text")
  observeEvent(
    input$updateBad,
    callModule(numericInputMod, "module", updateVal = 1)
  )
  observeEvent(
    input$updateBetter,
    callModule(numericInputMod, "module", updateVal = 2, displayText = "original text")
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The Bad Update overrides the original text with the default.  The Better Update avoids this by re-passing the original text but this isn't ideal because:

1. It requires at least two callModule() calls.
2. You must repeat the callModule() arguments.

Ideally, one callModule() call would take care of specifying the module arguments and the update behaviour.  I haven't found or thought up a way of doing this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `reactiveValues()`. You just need to make sure you allow for the reactive nature of the arguments you pass to the module:

```
library(shiny)

numericInputModUI <- function (id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    numericInput(ns("val"), "Value", value = 0),
    textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
}

numericInputMod <- function (input, output, session, updateVal = NA,
                             displayText = "default text", trig) {

  output$text <- renderText(displayText())

  observeEvent(trig(), ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "val", value = updateVal())
  })

}

ui = fluidPage(
  numericInputModUI("module"),
  actionButton("updateBad", label = "Bad Update"),
  actionButton("updateBetter", label = "Better Update")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  vals <- reactiveValues(dText = "original text", uVal = NA, trig = 0)

  observeEvent(input$updateBad, {
    vals$dText <- "default text"
    vals$uVal <- 1
    vals$trig <- vals$trig + 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$updateBetter, {
    vals$dText <- "original text"
    vals$uVal <- 2
    vals$trig <- vals$trig + 1
  })

  callModule(numericInputMod, "module", 
             displayText = reactive(vals$dText), 
             updateVal = reactive(vals$uVal),
             trig = reactive(vals$trig))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Looks like it should work.  I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Just tested it out. The update works, however a side effect is a given button cannot be used twice unless the other button is clicked in between.  For example, click Better Update, manually change the value back to 0, and try Better Update again.  It will work again if Bad Update is clicked before the second Better Update.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the code to include a third reactive value `trig` that will change every time a button is clicked regardless of the order, and set the `updateNumericInput` to run whenever this changes. this ensures the input updates on every click

Comment: Edited answer worked as advertised.  Marked as answered.